# How to avoid the Zoom of browser changing the Canvas size?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js, webgl

I'm buliding a Three.js project.
In JS, I defined that `renderer.setSize(1920，600)`.
With the command `renderer.domElement` in console I can check the renderer size.

Under the normal browser zoom ratio (100%), the size of canvas is 1920 x 600.
But if I change the zoom ratio to 150% then I got the wrong size 2880 x 900,which width and height are multiplied by 150%.

Generally speaking, if zoom ratio = z, then canvas width=1920z and height=600z .
This is not what I want! I want a fixed size 1920 x 600 ,which is not affected by the browser zoom ratio.

Strange situation ,anyone can solve this problem?

Comment: You should re-word your question as it is unclear what you are wanting/expecting. The behaviour you are getting (2880 x 900 as 150%) is exactly what I would expect as 1920 * 150% = 2880

Comment: Thhx  2pha. I mean I need a fixed size canvas (1920x600) ,which shouldn't be affected by the browser zoom ratio( changed by CTRL Num+ -).

Comment: @B.Law, is fullscreen mode an option? It should reset the page's zoom to 1. Alternatively, you could try to look to `devicePixelRatio` property and update your canvas' size accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Canvases have 2 sizes.

1. The size of their drawingBuffer.

   This is how many pixels are in the canvas. This is set by the `width`
   and `height` attributes

   ```
   <canvas width="123" height="456"></canvas>
   ```

   Or by setting the `width` and `height` properties

   ```
   someCanvas.width = 123;
   someCanvas.height = 456;
   ```
2. The size the canvas is displayed

   This is set by CSS

   ```
   <canvas width="123" height="456" style="width: 789px; height: 987px;"></canvas>
   ```

   That canvas will have 123x456 pixels displayed at 789x987px

The CSS size can be set to any valid CSS. For example `width: 50%;` in which case the browser will stretch the canvas to 50% of the size of its container. You can look up the size the browser is displaying the canvas i CSS pixels by looking at `canvas.clientWidth` and `canvas.clientHeight` or by calling `canvas.getClientBoundingRect()`.

The browser NEVER changes size #1 above. Size #2 only changes if you set it to some percent measure. If it's changing that's happening in your code somewhere. Check for a `resize` function

Note that three.js's `renderer.setSize` sadly sets the CSS for the canvas in JavaScript. If you don't want it to set the CSS pass in false as the last argument as in

```
renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
```

This is currently (as of 2015-11-29) undocumented.